# Problem with sorting teams in Lexicographic order

Tags: sorting, lambda

I was just trying to sort a list according to its last, second and first item.

```
a = [['Iran', 1, 1, 1, 0, 4], ['Morocco', 1, 2, 0, -2, 3],['Spain', 1, 0, 2, 2, 5],['Portugal', 1, 1, 1, 0, 4]]
```

for every list in the list "a", the **last item** is the *points of the team*, the **second** is the *wins*. I want to sort the list "a" , based on the points , if two or more teams have the same points , according to their wins and if the have both the same points and wins, based on their team name. I tried two ways. The first way was trying to sort them with lambda function:

```
a = sorted(a, key=lambda x:(x[-1],x[1],x[0])
```

The second way was:

```
    from operator import itemgetter
    a = sorted(a,key=itemgetter(-1,1,0))
```

but both ways gives the output :

```
[['Spain', 1, 0, 2, 2, 5], ['Portugal', 1, 1, 1, 0, 4], ['Iran', 1, 1, 1, 0, 4], ['Morocco', 1, 2, 0, -2, 3]]
```

But I expect something like this ,since Iran and Portugal have the same points and wins and according to 'Lexicographic order', Iran should come first not Portugal.

```
[['Spain', 1, 0, 2, 2, 5], ['Iran', 1, 1, 1, 0, 4], ['Portugal', 1, 1, 1, 0, 4], ['Morocco', 1, 2, 0, -2, 3]]
```

Comment: I tried it and I got the correct expected output `[['Morocco', 1, 2, 0, -2, 3], ['Iran', 1, 1, 1, 0, 4], ['Portugal', 1, 1, 1, 0, 4], ['Spain', 1, 0, 2, 2, 5]]`. Are you sure you got Portugal before Iran? Note that by default, `int`s are sorted in increasing order, so the first item in the list will be the country with the *least* points, not the most. You can fix that by using the optional keyword argument `reverse=True`, or by replacing `x[-1]` with `-x[-1]` in the lambda.

Comment: `>>> sorted(a, key=lambda x:(-x[-1], -x[1], x[0]))
[['Spain', 1, 0, 2, 2, 5], ['Iran', 1, 1, 1, 0, 4], ['Portugal', 1, 1, 1, 0, 4], ['Morocco', 1, 2, 0, -2, 3]]`

Comment: Thanks for the hint ! I didn't know that python had this feature .